# jquery ajax forces https

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, https, get

Following setup:

- jquery 2.1.1
- nodejs (not important)
- https

Problem: $.getJSON() and $.get() get a url like "http://host.com:1234/stats". The url parameter is definitely right (checked it with debug log). But jquery seems to automatically convert the http to https (what gives back a connection error). Mixed content is allowed.

Configuring SSL on the wanted hosts is not an option, because they aren't mine.

Do you guys know a trick to avoid jquery from preventing mixed content?

Thanks for your time and kind regards.

Comment: This is surely unrelated to jquery.

Comment: Can you show your network request log in your dev tools proving that the request is being sent over https instead of http?

Comment: https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=11841988

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the browser itself. The only solution is to use a reverse proxy.